# How to use getWords() function in TessBaseApi with android?

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I just made a simple image recognition app with android, however, I have a problem. I'm trying to make a border around the text like the link below by using the function getWords().getBoxRects(). But I'm not sure how I can use this function. There is not so much clear tutorial on the web so I thought that some pros here can give me some tip or example.

```
List<Rect> rectTextLines = baseApi.getTextlines().getBoxRects();
List<Rect> rectWords = baseApi.getWords().getBoxRects();
```

http://tech.jsa.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/131218.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getBoxRects()` returns an ArrayList of [Rects](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html). Just iterate over this list and draw each rectangle.

You could also try `PageIterator.`[getBoundingBox()](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/tess-two/src/com/googlecode/tesseract/android/PageIterator.java#L86). [Here](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/tess-two-test/src/com/googlecode/tesseract/android/test/TessBaseAPITest.java#L160) you can see how to use it to get all the bounding boxes at a given level (text lines, words etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the information. Your answer helped me solve the problem.